# SharePoint 2016 - NewForm.aspx- serialization error- The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: serialization

We have a very large list with more than 10,000 items. We can display the list. We can edit an exiting item from the list. But when we create a new item we get an error. as below:
Application error when access .../NewForm.aspx, Error=Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
We did following things suggested on internet. 
1. increased maxJsonLength big value very high in web.config. it did not help.
2. In web Application increased List View Threshold to 100,000 from 5000. But it did not help. 
I will request if any other suggestion somebody could offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above two points increasing maxJsonLength in web.config did not help and increasing Throttling related parameters from Central Adminstration did not help. The thing which fixed the problem suggested by somebody sorry I lost the link that advised to add following line into the NewForm.aspx. "CSRRenderMode... statement"